# SQL como faço um insert into em uma tabela que tem FK?

Tags: mysql, sql

Como faço um `insert into` em uma tabela onde existe uma FK?

exemplo essa é a minha estrutura

```
Pessoa
ID (primary key)
nome varchar(20)
id_endereco int not null (foreign key)
_______________________________________
endereco
ID (primary key)
rua varchar(50)
_______________________________________
```

em SQL eu fiz

```
create table endereco (
ID int primary key NOT NULL,
rua varchar(50)
);

create table pessoa (
ID int primary key NOT NULL,
nome varchar(50) NOT NULL,
id_endereco int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_idendereco FOREIGN KEY(id_endereco) REFERENCES pessoa(ID)
)
```

Aí na atividade pede que eu, adicione 20 pessoas...
o problema é que quando vou usar "insert into pessoa" não consigo adicionar as 20 pessoas por causa da foreign key, se nao tivesse ela, eu conseguia de boa.. mas como ela existe na tabela pessoa, aparece aquele erro.

Existe alguma forma de eu adicionar na tabela pessoa, não existindo nada no endereço? se não, o que eu faço?

```
insert into pessoa (id,nome,id_endereco)
values (1, "Jo Legendary", 1)
```

Comment: Coloque o código SQL que está a utilizar para fazer o `INSERT`. Provavelmente a coluna não aceita NULL.

Comment: Ao que parece, a FK não existe, já que a outta tabela não não possuí nenhum registro com esse campo estrangeiro. Coloque seu código para ficar mais fácil identificar.

Comment: Você primeiro tem que fazer o `insert` na tabela `endereco`, resgatar o `id` gerado e utilizá-lo para inserir o registro na tabela `cliente`.

Comment: Coloque a estrutura da sua tabela `endereco`.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos pronto, refiz mais ou menos o que eu queria explicar.. desculpa, quando eu fiz a pergunta era 5 da manhã eu tava muito cansado hehe

Comment: @JoãoMartins sim, a coluna nao pode aceitar null (editei a pergunta) nesse caso é obrigatório ter o endereço para criar a pessoa?, nessa atividade como eu faço para adicionar uma pessoa com essa fk para o id do endereço?

Comment: @RORSCHACH Bom dia! pronto botei a estrutura do problema e o sql que eu fiz :D

Comment: Basicamente não consegue inserir um registo na tabela `pessoa` sem primeiro ter um registo na tabela `endereco`.

Comment: @JoãoMartins certo, então no caso eu faço um insert no 'endereco' adicionando um ID e uma rua, e depois eu faço insert da pessoa colocando id, nome, e o id do endereço?

é que como a atividade tava pra adicionar a pessoa, eu nao sabia que tinha que fazer endereço primeiro...
porque na questão 1 era adicione '5' pessoas e na questão 3 era adicione '5' endereços.

Comment: @Jolegendary se calhar o professor fez assim mesmo para você perceber que não funciona dessa forma.

Comment: @Jolegendary dá para ver o seu `INSERT`?

Comment: oi @JorgeB. obrigado por comentar, botei no final da pergunta como mais ou menos eu tentei o insert na tabela pessoa... alguma sugestão? (to aprendendo sql agora)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como `id_endereco` é uma chave estrangeira, ele precisa que a referência exista.
Então para inserir uma pessoa com o `id_endereco = 10`, é necessário que na tabela `endereco` exista um registro com o `id = 10`.

Para inserir uma pessoa será necessário realizar 2 passos:

1. Inserir um registro na  tabela `endereco`:

   ```
   INSERT INTO endereco (ID, rua) VALUES (1, 'Rua Guanabara');
   ```

   Observe que o campo `ID` é uma chave primária(`PRIMARY KEY`), ou seja, não poderá ter nenhum registro com o mesmo valor. Então para cada endereço é necessário informar um `ID` diferente, uma forma de evitar isso é definir o campo como `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
2. Inserir um registro na tabela `pessoa`:

   ```
   INSERT INTO pessoa (ID, nome, id_endereco) VALUES (1, 'Roberto de Campos', 1);
   ```

   O `id_endereco` esta sendo preenchido com `1`, que é o `ID` referente ao endereço deste pessoa na tabela `endereco`. Caso o campo `ID` tabela `endereco` fosse `AUTO_INCREMENT`, você substituiria o `1` por `@@IDENTITY`, que seria retornado o último número inserido.

Ao realizar esses dois passos vocês estará com o registro da pessoa no banco de dados.

[Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f53/1) sem `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

[Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/064cf6/1) com `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Não precisa nada que a referência exista, apenas da um warning se for a 0 ou se inserir sem a referência.

Comment: oi, obrigado por me esclarecer a duvida... é aconselhável usar o AUTO_INCREMENT em todas as primary key?  ou eu posso ter algum tipo de problema caso usar em tudo.

Comment: Não é obrigatório, vai de caso a caso.

Answer (score 0):

Você enunciava o seu problema na pergunta «`id_endereco int (foreign key)` Lá de outra Tabela, que ainda ta vazia» (antes da edição). Se quer usar um `id_endereco` na inserção com valor maior que zero (0) tem de adicionar primeiro na outra tabela (endereco).

Por exemplo, se você quer inserir `id=1, nome="teste", id_endereco=9` na tabela `pessoa`, primeiro tem de inserir na tabela `endereco` o registo com `id=9` para que possa ser feita a associação.

---

Você também pode inserir sem referência para o `id_endereco`, resolvendo parcialmente o seu problema, basta inserir sem esse campo:

```
INSERT INTO pessoa ( Id, nome )
VALUES (1,"Pessoa1");
```

Mais ai vai ficar com o valor do `id_endereco` a zero (0), que é igual a fazer:

```
INSERT INTO pessoa ( Id, nome, id_endereco )
VALUES (2,"Pessoa2",0);
```

**Nota: Esta segunda forma só funciona se o *strict mode* não estiver ativo**

Comment: ah sim, desculpa... quando falei vazia eu quis me referir que existia as colunas, porém não tinha nenhum registro nela.

Comment: @Jolegendary leia de novo, editei agora mesmo.

Comment: Inserir sem referência não resolverá, quando você não informa o valor do campo no `INSERT` ele irá pegar o valor `DEFAULT`(que no caso não está definido) e se não tiver definido assumirá `NULL`. Porém, o campo `id_endereco` é `NOT NULL`, então seria retornado outro erro.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos você está enganado, o default para um inteiro é 0.

Comment: Montei um [exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa913f/1) pra você ver.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos esse exemplo está sem `NOT NULL` que é diferente.

Comment: Se colocar `NOT NULL`, o `INSERT` não funciona, é retornado o erro `Field 'inteiro1' doesn't have a default value`!

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84295/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-roberto-de-campos).